# Why does this TypeScript code fail to typecheck?

Tags: typescript

```
let a: { b: number }
let b: { b: number, c: number } = { b: 1, c: 2 }
a = { b: 1, c: 2 } // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties
a = b // OK
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20a%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20number%2C%20c%3A%20number%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%201%2C%20c%3A%202%20%7D%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%201%2C%20c%3A%202%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Object%20literal%20may%20only%20specify%20known%20properties%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20b%20%2F%2F%20Ok%0D%0A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript supports structural typing. When checking whether an object type B is a subtype of an object type A, excess properties of B don't matter. In an effort to catch more bugs, Typescript has a special case when it knows that the type B comes from an object literal. These are called fresh object literals, and are described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3115-excess-properties). The rationale is that the excess property is usually a typo. But when the type B can come from any object, not just an object literal, the usual structural typing rules apply, so there is no warning.

Comment: This is the answer, thanks @dimvar! Could you help me understand why `b`'s type isn't fresh, even when I remove its explicit annotation?


`let a: { b: number }; let b = { b: 1, c: 2 }; a = b // Ok`

It seems that object type freshness disappears not only when it's widened or asserted against, but also when it's assigned to a variable?

Comment: Right, the typechecker doesn't track the flow of the object literal. Freshness is only enforced at the place where the object literal is created.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all.

1. The first case fails because an *"[o]bject literal may only specify known properties"*, and `c` isn't a known property of `a`.
2. The second case succeeds because `b` is not an object literal, so the above rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me understand why `b` isn't an object literal?

Comment: Because it's a variable.